# How much IOCP queue size

Tags: windows, winapi, queue, iocp

How much could be the queue length in IO completion port?
Is any limit for accumulated not retrieved messages?
And what would be on comming over this bounder? Exception, blocking or missing new messages?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IO completion(`KQUEUE` object) port queue is based LIST_ENTRY circle list. no any size limitation

Comment: Circle list? Is oldest message overwritten if no free space?

Comment: no of course. nothing will be overwritten. are you familiar with lists based on LIST_ENTRY ? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff554296(v=vs.85).aspx